# Folding to a check

Tags: texas-hold-em

Once in a while, my post flop cards are so bad (no chance of making a hand), that, if, I am light into the pot, I will simply fold to a check....I don't want to be in the hand...maybe I need to go to the restroom...something...but playing the hand is trouble relative to the potential win.

I had a house tournament manager tell me that this was not OK...that it was an illegal fold.

Folding to a check is illegal ?

I can see in the WSOP rules that folding to a check is considered a binding fold, but I cant see that its illegal.

I dont see how it affects the hand in any way if I fold to a check.

Additionally, what if I got forced to fold in that situation by someone calling time on me ?  (weird, yes, but its possible according the the rule book)

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is acting out of turn, and unfair to other players. Floormen will usually just give warnings, but if the behavior continues, you could be ejected from the game.

Look at it from your opponents' point of view: Player A checks, you fold, now player B has to act--from his point of view, you have given player A information that he is not yet entitled to, harming B's chances to win. Perhaps, for example, player B opens: player A is now in last position to that bet, and may call with hands that he might have folded with a player yet to act behind him.

Comment: Also... your giving up overall edge in your game when you fold without action.

Comment: would folding if you are first to act still be unfair to the other players?

Comment: Absolutely. Understanding the value of information and player position are fundamental and critical concepts. If you don't understand them well enough to understand what's wrong with early folding, then you really have no business playing poker.

Comment: "you have given player A information that he is not yet entitled to" .     OK, I hear you, but how is that different from raising or checking ?  If I raise, I have given player A info.  If I check, I have given player A info.   Anything I do gives players that acted before me the same info as players acting after me.  

And the point about folding if you are first to act is a good one....you've disadvantaged no body.

If I simply sat and had the clock called on me, I would be forced to fold.

Some years ago, the on line poker systems let you fold anytime you wanted . FWIW

Comment: I can only explain, I can't make you understand...

Comment: @ScottMartin "If I check, I have given player A info". Not at all. Most players check 100% of the time to the preflop aggressor. He can expect you to check/raise him, check/call or check/fold at any point. When you muck he knows you won't call or raise, making his decision much easier. Your job is to make the game harder for your opponents. They'll know you have a strong hand when you don't muck, that's very very bad. More importantly, you'll never ever be able to get backdoor trips, two pairs or straights when you do this. It makes no sense to muck when you can check. You're burning money.

Comment: @ScottMartin You were told "you have given player A information that he is not yet entitled to". They key phrase there is "not entitled to". Other players are entitled to know your response when you have to act. They are not entitled to know what you would have done, if someone had raised, if there is in fact no raise on the table.

Comment: So, how about I just sit until someone calls the clock on me and I get forced to fold ?   Also, I dont agree with Jonast92 that folding to a check is always bad.  For one, it makes the other players think you are an idiot...which is good for me....and it confuses people (crazy poker playing makes you seem unpredictable) and lastly, it keeps you out of trouble with weird hands that can turn fear into greed.

Comment: And, to repeat something I said earlier, until recently, the online poker sites allowed you to fold anytime you wanted...even to a check...there was not rule against it...Some of them have removed that just because of folks being prone to click it accidentally.    Anynow, none of the responses here have convinced me that its unfair to fold to a check...I dont HAVE to stay in a hand if I dont want to.

Comment: Online it isn't an issue. When you fold online, the software doesn't inform any of the other players until you are actually facing a bet; until then, it checks for you. If the software doesn't do this, it's broken. If you deliberately sit still until someone calls a clock and are forced to fold, then you're an even bigger asshole than someone who just folds out of turn, and I would expect the floorman to eject you from the game or tournament. As a floorman, I certainly would have.

Comment: I'm not folding out of turn...its my turn to act.  there is a check, and I fold...unless you're saying that that constitutes folding out of turn.   But, yes, stalling until forced to fold is a asshole move...I was pointing it out as a theoretical....regardless, I will continue to believe that I can fold any time I want.. as long as its my turn to act.

Answer (score 0):

Been playing over 20+ years.  The only thing folding says is... I don't want to play this hand.  It's my money, my time and my option.  I think it's a dumb rule to make me stay in a hand I don't want to play.  When I play, I'm not trying to aid players before or behind me.  Also in tourneys, where time is running, the faster the game is played, the more hands can be seen with smaller Blinds.   Now, if this rule is stated to limit the appearance of collusion, then maybe.